# PhoneGap 1.5 external url issue

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created an app that contains many internal company jquery mobile pages and they all work perfectly in the android simulator. However, I am having problem with the external urls. I have Jquery Google maps plugin which needs google maps api url.

So, If I have

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

in my index page. Then that index page is not loading. If I remove that external url then page loads fine without google map functionality.

I researched that external urls should be added in the cordova.xml file. So, I added.

```
   <access origin="http://maps.google.com*"/>
```

But still the google maps url is causing the same problem. My company also has an outbound proxy is that causing an problem??

Comment: Run "adb logcat" to see what errors if any are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the star. Everything before it is a complete origin address.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  * to the XML file instead of http://maps.google.com*

With this method, you will be able to access any site you link to in your app, not just Google.